# Prevent execution of parent event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tree of divs:

```
<div id="a" onclick="func">
    <div id="b" onclick="func">
         <div id="c" onclick="func">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a click is made on a div it makes it's children invisible - ie click on "a" will turn "b" and "c" invisible.

```
function func{
   if ($(childId).hasClass("visible")){
    $(childId).removeClass("visible");
    $(childId).addClass("invisible");
}
```

The problem is: a click on "b" will call "a"'s click and make "b" and "c" invisible. How do I disable the click on "a" using jQuery?

thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can add a handler for the child that will prevent the click event from propagating up:

```
function handler(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // now do your stuff        
}
$('#a').add('#b').click(handler);
```

This way clicks to `'#b'` will not propagate to `'#a'`. Neither will clicks to `'#c'` go to `'#b'`, and hence not to `'#a'`.

Comment: This is pretty cool, even works with $(".clickyClass a").click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation();}); assuming .clickyClass has a click handler

Comment: should this also prevent from bootstrap `data-toggle="collapse"` on parent from working? because i try and fail :(

Answer (score 11):

use

[event.stopPropagation()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29)

> Stops the bubbling of an event to
>   parent elements, preventing any parent
>   handlers from being notified of the
>   event.

when click on b and c

Answer (score 1):

I have  the following `html`structure:

```
<a href="http://example.com">
    <div> 
       <button type="button">Save</button>
    </div>
</a>
```

and I want to prevent new page being opened when button is clicked.

I found that `stopPropagation` alone is not enough. The handler should also `return false`.

```
$('button').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        save();
        return false;
});
```