# Prevent parent container click event from firing when hyperlink clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

On my web page I have a list of files.

Each file is in it's own container div (div class="file"). Inside the container is a link to the file and a description.

I wanted to allow a user to click anywhere on the container to download the file. I did this by adding a click event to the container and retrieving the href of the child link.

As the file opens in a new window, if the user actually clicks the link, the file opens twice.

So I need to prevent the parent container click event from firing when the hyperlink is clicked. Would the best way of doing this be to add a click function to the hyperlink to0 and set `event.stopPropagation`? Presumably this would then stop the event from bubbling up to the container.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use stopPropagation.  See: [Prevent execution of parent event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/how-to-disable-parent-click)

Comment: Works without jQuery. 

    onClickHandler(event) { event.stopPropagation(); }

Answer (score 19):

In the Microsoft model you must set the event’s cancelBubble property to true.

```
window.event.cancelBubble = true;
```

In the W3C model you must call the event’s stopPropagation() method.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Here's a cross-browser solution if you're not using a framework:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: This is a little confusing since you don't show what attaches to what.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the help.

I was using jQuery but it's good to know a non-framework solution.

Added the following for the links:

```
$(".flink").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having exactly this problem, which was quite annoying to debug and this solved it. In my case I had a click handler for .pub and then added the line $(".pub a").click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});

Comment: doesn't returning false from the event handler function have the same effect?

Comment: @Johnus - no it doesn't - see http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/