# DOM Level 0 event: how to prevent the outer click from firing?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Check the following code:

```
​<div onclick="alert('Hi, from outer div!');">
    <button onclick="alert('Hi, from button!');">Tha button</button>, Click me!
</div>​​​​
```

Is there a way to prevent the outer div from firing an onclick when I click the button? Any idea how to cancel DOM level 0 events?​​

Note: I can't use jQuery. It needs to work on Chrome, FireFox, IE6-9.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: you might wanna [read this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) for starters

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent parent container click event from firing when hyperlink clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997084/prevent-parent-container-click-event-from-firing-when-hyperlink-clicked) ... look at the highest voted answer instead of the selected one (if you are not using jQuery).

Comment: @FelixKling, I'm using level 1 dom events without handlers, that might be a big difference...

Comment: You are using handlers, what do you think the code in `onclick` is? Have you tried it at all?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: Actually, you're using "DOM0" handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In most standard browsers, you call `stopPropagation` on the event object ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ehequt) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ehequt/edit#html)):

```
​<div onclick="alert('Hi, from outer div!');">
    <button onclick="alert('Hi, from button!'); event.stopPropagation();">Tha button</button>, Click me!
</div>​​​​
```

In older copies of IE, you have to set the `cancelBubble` property to `true` instead:

```
​<div onclick="alert('Hi, from outer div!');">
    <button onclick="alert('Hi, from button!'); event.cancelBubble = false;">Tha button</button>, Click me!
</div>​​​​
```

...which means for broad compatibility you have to test which you're dealing with, which gets ugly ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ezemiy) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ezemiy/edit#html)):

```
​<div onclick="alert('Hi, from outer div!');">
    <button onclick="alert('Hi, from button!'); if (event.stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); } else { event.cancelBubble = true; }">Tha button</button>, Click me!
</div>​​​​
```

These sorts of differences are why I always recommend moving away from the old DOM0-style handler and using a decent JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). These smooth over differences between browsers and provide a huge amount of utility functionality.

For example, with jQuery, this HTML:

```
​<div id="theDiv">
    <button id="theButton">Tha button</button>, Click me!
</div>​​​​
```

...and this script ([live example](http://jsbin.com/uhumeg) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uhumeg/edit#html)):

```
$("#theDiv").click(function() {
    alert('Hi, from outer div!');
});
$("#theButton").click(function(event) {
    alert('Hi, from button!');
    event.stopPropagation(); // Even on IE, jQuery provides this
});
```

Or frequently with jQuery, you see people just doing `return false;` in their event handler. `return false;` in a handler, *in jQuery*, does two things: Stops propagation, and prevents any default action the event might have had (for instance, in a click handler on a link). `stopPropgation` doesn't prevent the default.

But this isn't meant to be an advertisement for jQuery (though it is a very good library overall). Closure, YUI, Prototype, and all the others have similar functionality for letting you not worry about these sorts of browser incompatibilities.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: IE6 and IE7 definitely don't have `stopPropagation`. I don't remember whether IE8 does. IE9, IE10, and up do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Any idea how can I get the stopPropagation to work in earlier browsers?

Comment: @Kees: It should be `event.cancelBubble = false` (as shown in the question I linked to as duplicate ;)).

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: This is why I use a library. Fixed (`returnValue` = `preventDefault()`; `cancelBubble` = `stopPropagation()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="alert('Hi, from outer div!');">
    <button onclick="event.stopPropagation(); alert('Hi, from button!');">Tha button</button>, Click me!
</div>​
```

What I added was an event.stopPropagation();
What this does is that is stops the bubbling from occurring

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: In this context, yes; but `event.stopPropgation()` does not, older versions of IE don't have it.