# Make the click on inner div not to call the outer one's onClick function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent parent container click event from firing when hyperlink clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997084/prevent-parent-container-click-event-from-firing-when-hyperlink-clicked)

I have

```
<div onClick="someJScode();">
  ...
  <div></div>
  ...
</div>
```

I don't want `someJScode()` to be called when the inner div is clicked. How to do this?

Comment: We don't write code for you here at SO. We are here to help debug code. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('yourinnerDiv').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()});`

This will stop click event bubbling up the DOM.
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation

Comment: assuming hes using jquery. If so, he should use .on and not .click ~debatable though. shortcuts are ok

Comment: Added cross-browser code (IE < 9)

Comment: @ic3b3rg: This answer uses jQuery and jQuery takes care of it.

Comment: @FelixKling Good to know! rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div onClick="someJScode();" class="parent">
  <div class="child" onclick="childCallback(event)"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function someJScode() {
    alert('Click!');
}

function childCallback(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/Fy6dg/)**

The code above uses [stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopImmediatePropagation) You can also use [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation)

Here is more generic solution:

```
var preventChildrenPropagation = (function (parentClass) {
    var preventPropagation = function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    return function (parent) {
        var foreach = Array.prototype.forEach;
        foreach.call(document.getElementsByClassName(parent), function (e) {
            foreach.call(e.children, function (c) {
                c.onclick = preventPropagation;
            });
        });
    }
}());

preventChildrenPropagation('parent');
```

The method `preventChildrenPropagation` will prevent the propagation of all `click` events of all children of the "parent" element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: Why not just `stopPropagation`?

Comment: Habit from jQuery... :-)