# how to ignore checkbox inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I am using jQuery's event delegation to add a click event to table rows. I also have a checkbox in the first td of the row. When I click anywhere in the row everything works as expected. However, I don't want the event to work when I click in the checkbox. I've tried using the :not() selector but perhaps I am missing something as I am still triggering the event when I click in the checkbox.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="myCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="userName" /></div>
    </td>
    <td><a href="/go/to/user/profile"></a></td>
    <td>more info</td>
    <td>more info</td>
    <td>more info</td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('table tr:not(':checkbox')').on('click', 'td', function(event) {

    // Do something
});
```

Can I get help fixing what I am attempting to do please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/prevent-execution-of-parent-event-handler)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options (both involve removing the `tr:not` stuff from your existing code, which as you say doesn't work — `tr` elements can't be checkboxes, and `:not` checks the element, not its contents):

1. Add an event handler to the checkbox that calls [`e.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). Then the click event won't reach the row. You can do that either directly or via delegation. [Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/ewoder) going direct. If you go indirect, be sure to test clicking `label`s that activate the checkbox (if you're going to have them) on all of the browsers you intend to support.

   or
2. Add this to your handler:

   ```
   if ($(event.target).is('input[type=checkbox]')) {
       return;
   }
   ```

   E.g.:

   ```
   $('table').on('click', 'td', function(event) {

       if ($(event.target).is('input[type=checkbox]')) {
           return;
       }

       // Logic here
   });
   ```

   That works by testing the source of the event to see if it's a checkbox, and bailing early.

In both cases, if you use a `label` to activate the checkbox, you may need to do the same thing for the label.

I got curious about what #2 would look like handling `label`s, and it turns out it's enough code to move into a function, but not hard &mdash probably how I'd go: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ewoder/4) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ewoder/4/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // The table cell click handler
  $("table").on("click", "td", function(e) {
    // Is the source a checkbox or the label for
    // one?
    if (isCheckbox($(e.target))) {
      return;
    }

    // Normal handling
    $(this).toggleClass("foo");
  });

  // Function to test whether the source is a
  // checkbox, or the label of a checkbox
  function isCheckbox($elm) {
    var chkid;

    if ($elm.is("input[type=checkbox]")) {
      return true;
    }
    if ($elm.is("label")) {
      chkid = $elm.attr("for");
      if (chkid) {
        return $("#" + chkid).is("input[type=checkbox]");
      }
      return !!$elm.find("input[type=checkbox]")[0];
    }
    return false;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using stopPropagation() to prevent event from bubbling.

```
$('div.myCheckbox input[type=checkbox]').bind('change', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: The `change` event is irrelevant to the click on the table cell.