# jQuery .click on element with element behind stacking error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 'lightbox' similar function which simply brings up 2 divs like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3ZhEz.jpg]

The green color (wont be colored in once it works) is the area to click to close the login box.

jsFiddle with code:
http://jsfiddle.net/bhcGv/8/

When you click on the login box it will disappear as it thinks its clicking on the green box. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/prevent-execution-of-parent-event-handler)

Comment: change `z-index: -1;` of `#centeredBox` to 1 or more.

Comment: @loler my bad, updated jsfiddle a few moments ago however that is not preventing the issue

Comment: @zomboble: The fiddle still does not show anything for me. This one does: http://jsfiddle.net/bhcGv/9/. However, the solution to the problem is in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @Flater that could be a reason of problem, but there was a second reason which i did not notice at first. `#centeredBox` is inside of div `#loginOffBox` that's why `.stopPropagation` is needed.

Comment: @Loler: there isn't any other explanation for an event bubbling up, other than it being placed inside the other element in the DOM. Visual styling will never influence the working of the DOM. CSS != Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need .stopPropagation method.

here the updated jsfidle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhcGv/10/

Answer (score 1):

you could add this code

```
.find('#centeredBox').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
return false;
    });
```

so your document.ready function becomes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginOffBox").click(function(){
        $('#loginOffBox').hide();
          $('#centeredBox').hide();
    }).find('#centeredBox').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
return false;
    });
    // other js
});
```

this should stop the event from being run when you click on the centered div.

You could also take the centered div out of the colored one too. then you wont have the event bubbles.

Comment: Either call `e.stopPropegation();` or `return false;` but both is redundant.

Comment: I changed the spelling mistake  in `e.stopPropegation();` in the post to `e.stopPropagation();` sometime after @FelixKling's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to fix the z-index of the two divs. Background div should have a smaller z-index than the popup div and both should have a relatively high value.

Try z-index of 1000 for loginOffBox and 1100 for centeredBox and it should work fine.

Comment: Yep, almost forgot to add, It might not be necessary to have the background div a parent to the centered div. they both can be siblings if they are positioned appropriately in css. Then there is not need for special event capturing.