# jQuery ignoring child elements events

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following list:

```
  <ul id="menu">
            <li style="background-image:url('Images/X-AFH-Company-Office-Background.png')" id="office">
                <!-- <div style="width:250px;height:300px;position:absolute;" ></div>-->
                <div >Company / Office</div>
                <img src="Images/Employee.png"  onmouseover="this.src='Images/Employee-Stroke.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/Employee.png'" />
                <img class="stroke" style="display:none"  src="Images/Employee-Stroke.png" />
            </li>
            <li  style="background-image:url('Images/X-AFH-Hospital-Clinic-Background.png')" id="clinic" >
                <div >Hospital / Clinic</div>
                <img src="Images/Doctor.png"  onmouseover="this.src='Images/Doctor-Stroke.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/Doctor.png'" />
               <div style="width:100px;height:350px;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:21"></div>
                                </li>
            <li style="background-image:url('Images/X-AFH-University-School-Background.png')" id="school">
                 <div >University / School</div>
                <img src="Images/Student.png"  onmouseover="this.src='Images/Student-Stroke.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/Student.png'" />

            </li>
etc...
```

And have a click event on the main `<li>` on that list. However, the `<img />` tags are overflowing from their parent `<li>`s and are triggering the click event.

How can I only restrict the click event for the list item rather than their children? Even if they are going beyond the width and height of the main li.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/prevent-execution-of-parent-event-handler)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the child elements to stop it triggering.

Here's an example restricting all images which are children of list elements from triggering an alert:

```
$("li").click(function(e) {
   alert("Clicking on the li will trigger this, not the img children");
});

$("li img").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); // The img children inside li will not trigger the li event.
});
```

[**jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/D3HEh/)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the existing answer, you can simply compare the `event.target` against `this` (the element the click handler is bound to):

```
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target === this) {
     // code is only executed when li is clicked
   }
});
```

#### [Here's a simple demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bEbWQ/)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [Event Capturing and bubbling in javascript](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing).  You can find more details in the link provided.

You can prevent this using [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fevent.stopPropagation).

Comment: @Zenith I also came across the same problem in `javascript`.  I just missed the link that took a lot of time for me.  I tried to explain the cause with a solution.  If this is wrong, please excuse me.