# how can I make just child invoked when I click on child in the div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple scenario: I have two div one inside another, I want when I click on the child div just child div invokes and when I click on parent the parent one invoke but in the example below as you can see when I click on child both are invoked.Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#t1").click(function(){alert("Parent")});
 $("#t2").click(function(){alert("child")});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/hv6dv/

can anyone help?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#t1").click(function(){alert("Parent")});
     $("#t2").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();alert("child")});
});`   http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/hv6dv/1/

Comment: You should try researching it before posting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/prevent-execution-of-parent-event-handler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should stop the event from bubbling up the DOM tree(any parent handlers from being notified of the event) using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/). Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#t1").click(function(){alert("Parent")});
     $("#t2").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();alert("child")});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hv6dv/2/)**

Comment: Thanks but now when I did that just parent alert execute and alert for child never execute!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** here to prevent click event buble up the DOM tree from your child div `#t2` to parent div `#t1`

```
$("#t2").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    alert("child")
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hv6dv/3/)**