# buttons in clickable div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have whole div you can click on which toggles the main part of that div. The problem is I also have clickable button in that div and when I click on it it does what it should but also toggles the whole div at the same time!

How can I disable that ?

Comment: Could you share your code please, it makes answering a lot easier and more effective.

Comment: exact duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/prevent-execution-of-parent-event-handler)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` on button click

It will stop the propagatotin to the parent

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation() 
});
```