# jQuery - if a class appears on the DOM and then wrapper is clicked remove that class again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

What I am trying to do is check if a class is active with hasClass. If it is active and then the wrapper is clicked remove that class from the wrapper again.

This is what I have to remove the class:

```
 $(function() {
    $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
        // Calling a function in case you want to expand upon this.
        toggleNav();

        $('#site-wrapper.show-nav').click(function (){
            $(this).removeClass('show-nav');
        });
        console.log('it worked');
    });
});
```

But this code is removing the class as soon as it is clicked without checking "if" it is present. Even if it is not present, it removes it.

The

Comment: Binding an event handler inside another event handler is probably not what you want. *"Even if it is not present, it removes it."* How can something be removed if it doesn't exist? That doesn't  make any sense.

Comment: what I meant was, the button to add the class "show-nav" is contained inside "site-wrapper". So because we are clicking inside site-wrapper and the button is inside that div it is firing both events.

Comment: Then stop the even from propagating. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1398582/218196

Comment: ah thank you, that is what I was seeking, if you post the answer i will accept.

Comment: Duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1398582/218196)

Comment: tried searching before my post but to no avail, can't delete my post now that it has answers... :(

Answer (score 0):

Have the if statement within the click function

```
    $('#site-wrapper').click(function (){
       if ($('#site-wrapper').hasClass('show-nav')) {
         $('#site-wrapper').removeClass('show-nav');
       }
    })
```

Comment: same problem it is removing the class simultaneously as it is added. because I am adding the class with a button which is inside the site-wrapper.

Comment: you need to add the class in an else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#site-wrapper').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('show-nav')) {
        $(this).removeClass('show-nav');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('show-nav');
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C5F95/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#site-wrapper.show-nav').click(function (){
        $(this).removeClass('show-nav');
    });
```