# jQuery - Select the most accurate node

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML structure :

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">
        content1
        <ul>
            <li class="foo">
                content2
                <ul>
                    <li class="foo">
                        content3
                        <!-- N levels of depth -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to retrieve the second `<li>` element (containing "content2") on a click event. I'm currently using this method :

```
$('body').on('click', '.foo', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Do something with the element
});
```

However, as you can guess, this will also select the parent element as it also contains a `foo` class. I would like select the most "accurate" node without triggering the event for the parent element (eg: if I click on content3, it should only trigger the event for this element, not his parents).

Any suggestion ?

Comment: *"I would like to retrieve the second `<li>` element (containing "content2") on a click event."* Always, no matter which `.foo` was clicked? I understand the second part of the question ([which is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1398582/218196) btw), but the first parts confuses me.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Never use `body` for delegated event handlers. Due to styling it can have a 0 calculated height and not receive bubbled mouse events! Always use `document` as your default. Much safer.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I don't. The project is actually using more accurate selectors. I wrote `body` to remove all the project-specific stuff :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Good point, but you could say this about any other element as well. And one typically binds the handler to the closest container in the document. So, generally saying one should always bind to `document` isn't very helpful.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Hence "*as your default*" (meaning if nothing closer is available). `body` is used so often I like to warn of its problems :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Ok, if that is what this was implying then I agree :)

Answer (score 4):

Luckily there is a very straightforward solution to this one!

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    // Do something with the element
});
```

Comment: Never use `body` for delegated event handlers. Due to styling it can have a 0 calculated height and not receive bubbled mouse events! Always use `document` as your default. Much safer.

Comment: Ah, good point!  I'll correct that in my answer.