# How to prevent click event from outer div if inner div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, click

I have 2 divs with a js click event. One div is located in the other one.

But I dont want the outer div's click event to be triggered if I click the inner one. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/prevent-execution-of-parent-event-handler)

Answer (score 5):

By default, event handling starts at the lowest level of the DOM where you have defined a handler to handle the target event. Assuming you have defined event listeners higher in the parent chain to handle the same event, you will need to [stop the propagation of the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) if you do not wish for the event to be handled beyond the layer you intend for it to be handled in:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

See what happens when you remove that line in the example below:

```js
document.querySelector('.inner').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert('inner div clicked!');
  e.stopPropagation();
});

document.querySelector('.outer').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('outer div clicked!');
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  Outer
  <div class='inner'>
    Inner
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use event.stopPropagation();

Like this

```
document.getElementById("#seconddiv").addEventListener("click", function($event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: thx :) but after some research I found a better way to directly call the inner div's click event without triggering the outer one's one. It looks like `$('.class1').add('.class2').click(some_function);` the problem is now that I need to call the click event on the document because my div isn't existing if my js code is read. `$(document).on('click', ".class2", function(e){});` how can I call `$('.class1').add('.class2').click(some_function);` on the document?

Answer (score 2):

Use event.stopPropagation:

```
document.getElementById('inner').addEventListener('click', function (event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log ('Inner div clicked!');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4L87qLte/